# Use addAccountExplicitly by 2 different apps with same account name and account type

Tags: android, accountmanager

1. If 2 different apps use addAccountExplicitly to create account in Android account manager with same Account type and account name then is it possible?
2. What will happen if both are signed by different certs? Or both have different authenticator xml?
3. Does different package name have any role to play?

I think whichever app creates the account first will be able to use it and second app will fail to create a new one and also fail to access it as they are not signed with same cert and authenticator is also different

Answer (score 1):

If two applications use same account type to provide their custom account type, app which is installed first would work.

Comment: How can we detect what is the other app that do so programmatically? So that if we detect that issue on the user side, we can programmatically inform them of this issue ahead.